# Remove all except of two strings in Notepad++

Tags: list, replace, find, notepad++

I want to know the following thing.

I have a huge name&hash database.

```
Stuart L : wow@thisemail.com : 58d5c2b76560bb0e557ced5aabaabbfd08295161 : 5c5118dse

Daniel HH : dd@kdkd.com : 03d09e27edaec2a1f70ww828ce788fb522ac0b43 : fe52122cd
```

This is how i want it:

```
58d5c2b76560bb0e557ced5aabaabbfd08295161:5c5118dse
03d09e27edaec2a1f70ww828ce788fb522ac0b43:fe52122cd
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please remember to include (in addition to sample input and output data), what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started:
Search for: `^[\w ]+ : [\w.@]+ : ([a-z0-9]+) : ([a-z0-9]+)$`
Replace with: `\1:\2`

The search expression uses start and end of line anchors. It scans the respective line for sequences of characters as in your examples, and captures the two, you are interested in.

See it in action: [RegEx 101](https://regex101.com/r/nT6eQ2/1).

Please comment, if and as this requires adjustment / further detail.

Comment: @user4221591 What exactly do you need more detail on?

Comment: In the reply you mention Replace with: `\1:\2` . What does '\1:\2' mean? I understood the working of **Search for: regex** but can not understand '\1:\2' working. Please can you explain. Thank you !!!

Comment: @user4221591 `\1` and `\2` are each backreferences to the parts of the search expression captured using `( )`. These are separated by the verbatim `:`, OP asked for. You might want to play with [RegEx 101](https://regex101.com/r/nT6eQ2/1)...